# Color a block of texts inside tabbing

Tags: color, tabbing

I am editing a frame of a presentation in `beamer`. This frame has 2 parts side by side. The left side is a program by `tabbing` containing 5 lines:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A motivating example}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
      \begin{framed}
        \resizebox{0.85\textwidth}{!}{%
          \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tabbing}
              \quad \= \hspace{-0.3cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{0cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
              1 \> \> line 1 \\
              2 \> \> line 2 \\
              3 \> \> line 3 \\
              4 \> \> line 4 \\
              5 \> \> line 5
            \end{tabbing}
          \end{minipage}}
      \end{framed}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    ...
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I would like to make Lines 3, 4 and 5 in blue, instead of black. I try to put `\color{blue}` in front of `3`, but it doesn't color things after `3`. I try to put `\textcolor{blue}{...line 3...line 4...line 5...}`, but it gives an error.

Does anyone know if it is possible to color 3 lines together?

Comment: each tabbing cell is a separate box, so you can put `\color` in each cell

Comment: sure, I am wondering if it is possible to color a block, because I have more than 5 lines, and i will change colors quite often...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly this is gross abuse of syntax, and you didn't hear this from me...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
              \quad \= \hspace{-0.3cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{-0.1cm} \quad \= \hspace{0cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
              1 \> \> line 1 \\
              2 \> \> line 2 \\[0pt \color{red}]
              3 \> \> line 3 \\
              4 \> \> line 4 \\[0pt \color{green}]
              5 \> \> line 5
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```